# Changing js array on a html

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to  manipulate an js array after a click but its not triggering.

example is here

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

what did i do is: (i need to re set dataset which is loaded into table previously please take a look at above example)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".retrievemenu").click(function() {
    //alert( this.id );
    //$('#menus').hide();
    var restid = this.id;
    data = [
      ["sasa", "a", "a"]
    ];
    $.post("server.php", {
      retrievemenu: 1,
      restid: restid
    }, function(data) {

      console.log(data);
      $('#menus').hide();
      $('#menus').DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [{
            title: "Restaurant Name"
          }, {
            title: "Menu Name"
          }, {
            title: "Actions"
          }

        ]
      });
      $('#menus').show();

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The AJAX response argument doesn't overwrite your higher scoped `data` var.

Comment: how can i do that?  want to edit data in anywhere in document this cant overwrite  dataSet2 = [["sasa","a","a"]];

Comment: Choose a different `var` name than your argument name, and use assignment, or Array manipulation methods.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=menus - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3